# How to calculate CRC of a 64Bit DLL in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll, crc32

I am using following code to calculate CRC32 of 32Bit DLLs.

```
//Code to Check CRC of DLL files
procedure CalcCRC32(FileName: String; var CRC32: dword);
const Table: Array[0..255] of DWord =
     ($00000000, $77073096, $EE0E612C, $990951BA,
      $076DC419, $706AF48F, $E963A535, $9E6495A3,
      $0EDB8832, $79DCB8A4, $E0D5E91E, $97D2D988,
      $09B64C2B, $7EB17CBD, $E7B82D07, $90BF1D91,
      $1DB71064, $6AB020F2, $F3B97148, $84BE41DE,
      $1ADAD47D, $6DDDE4EB, $F4D4B551, $83D385C7,
      $136C9856, $646BA8C0, $FD62F97A, $8A65C9EC,
      $14015C4F, $63066CD9, $FA0F3D63, $8D080DF5,
      $3B6E20C8, $4C69105E, $D56041E4, $A2677172,
      $3C03E4D1, $4B04D447, $D20D85FD, $A50AB56B,
      $35B5A8FA, $42B2986C, $DBBBC9D6, $ACBCF940,
      $32D86CE3, $45DF5C75, $DCD60DCF, $ABD13D59,
      $26D930AC, $51DE003A, $C8D75180, $BFD06116,
      $21B4F4B5, $56B3C423, $CFBA9599, $B8BDA50F,
      $2802B89E, $5F058808, $C60CD9B2, $B10BE924,
      $2F6F7C87, $58684C11, $C1611DAB, $B6662D3D,
      $76DC4190, $01DB7106, $98D220BC, $EFD5102A,
      $71B18589, $06B6B51F, $9FBFE4A5, $E8B8D433,
      $7807C9A2, $0F00F934, $9609A88E, $E10E9818,
      $7F6A0DBB, $086D3D2D, $91646C97, $E6635C01,
      $6B6B51F4, $1C6C6162, $856530D8, $F262004E,
      $6C0695ED, $1B01A57B, $8208F4C1, $F50FC457,
      $65B0D9C6, $12B7E950, $8BBEB8EA, $FCB9887C,
      $62DD1DDF, $15DA2D49, $8CD37CF3, $FBD44C65,
      $4DB26158, $3AB551CE, $A3BC0074, $D4BB30E2,
      $4ADFA541, $3DD895D7, $A4D1C46D, $D3D6F4FB,
      $4369E96A, $346ED9FC, $AD678846, $DA60B8D0,
      $44042D73, $33031DE5, $AA0A4C5F, $DD0D7CC9,
      $5005713C, $270241AA, $BE0B1010, $C90C2086,
      $5768B525, $206F85B3, $B966D409, $CE61E49F,
      $5EDEF90E, $29D9C998, $B0D09822, $C7D7A8B4,
      $59B33D17, $2EB40D81, $B7BD5C3B, $C0BA6CAD,
      $EDB88320, $9ABFB3B6, $03B6E20C, $74B1D29A,
      $EAD54739, $9DD277AF, $04DB2615, $73DC1683,
      $E3630B12, $94643B84, $0D6D6A3E, $7A6A5AA8,
      $E40ECF0B, $9309FF9D, $0A00AE27, $7D079EB1,
      $F00F9344, $8708A3D2, $1E01F268, $6906C2FE,
      $F762575D, $806567CB, $196C3671, $6E6B06E7,
      $FED41B76, $89D32BE0, $10DA7A5A, $67DD4ACC,
      $F9B9DF6F, $8EBEEFF9, $17B7BE43, $60B08ED5,
      $D6D6A3E8, $A1D1937E, $38D8C2C4, $4FDFF252,
      $D1BB67F1, $A6BC5767, $3FB506DD, $48B2364B,
      $D80D2BDA, $AF0A1B4C, $36034AF6, $41047A60,
      $DF60EFC3, $A867DF55, $316E8EEF, $4669BE79,
      $CB61B38C, $BC66831A, $256FD2A0, $5268E236,
      $CC0C7795, $BB0B4703, $220216B9, $5505262F,
      $C5BA3BBE, $B2BD0B28, $2BB45A92, $5CB36A04,
      $C2D7FFA7, $B5D0CF31, $2CD99E8B, $5BDEAE1D,
      $9B64C2B0, $EC63F226, $756AA39C, $026D930A,
      $9C0906A9, $EB0E363F, $72076785, $05005713,
      $95BF4A82, $E2B87A14, $7BB12BAE, $0CB61B38,
      $92D28E9B, $E5D5BE0D, $7CDCEFB7, $0BDBDF21,
      $86D3D2D4, $F1D4E242, $68DDB3F8, $1FDA836E,
      $81BE16CD, $F6B9265B, $6FB077E1, $18B74777,
      $88085AE6, $FF0F6A70, $66063BCA, $11010B5C,
      $8F659EFF, $F862AE69, $616BFFD3, $166CCF45,
      $A00AE278, $D70DD2EE, $4E048354, $3903B3C2,
      $A7672661, $D06016F7, $4969474D, $3E6E77DB,
      $AED16A4A, $D9D65ADC, $40DF0B66, $37D83BF0,
      $A9BCAE53, $DEBB9EC5, $47B2CF7F, $30B5FFE9,
      $BDBDF21C, $CABAC28A, $53B39330, $24B4A3A6,
      $BAD03605, $CDD70693, $54DE5729, $23D967BF,
      $B3667A2E, $C4614AB8, $5D681B02, $2A6F2B94,
      $B40BBE37, $C30C8EA1, $5A05DF1B, $2D02EF8D);

var F: file;
    BytesRead: dword;
    Buffer: Array[1..65521] of byte;
    i: Word;
begin
    FileMode := 0;
    CRC32 := $ffffffff;
    {$I-}
    AssignFile(F, FileName);
    Reset(F, 1);
    if IOResult = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        BlockRead(F, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead);
        for i := 1 to BytesRead do CRC32 := (CRC32 shr 8) xor Table[Buffer[i] xor (CRC32 and $000000FF)];
      until BytesRead = 0;
    end;
    CloseFile(F);
    {$I+}
    CRC32 := not CRC32;
end;
```

Now I want to do the same for 64Bit DLLs in my 64Bit application.

But above code always returning 0.

I am not able to convert this code. Can someone please guide me here.

TIA

Yogi Yang

Comment: `not $ffffffff = 0` so i'm guessing which the file youcannot be opened. Also why   you are not  using a `TFileStream` and the `TIdHashCRC32` (IdHashCRC) class?

Comment: Becoz this is an age old script and has been working properly for all these years

Comment: @Yogi It still works. Even in your 64 bit program. You've just misdiagnosed the failure mode.

Comment: maybe consider using the crc32 function from zlib

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo, zlib uses "Adler checksum", not CRC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason for CRC of a 32-bit DLL to behave differently to CRC of a 64-bit DLL. CRC simply works on a file as is.

> **SIDE NOTE**: The 32 in CRC32 has nothing to do with whether the app/dll or whatever is 32-bit. (You can run a CRC on a text file if you choose.) The 32 refers to the size of the check value i.e. 32-bits.

Your code is deliberately ***hiding*** IO errors: First with `{$I-}` and then by quietly doing nothing if `IOResult` <> 0. Hiding errors is a ***terrible*** thing to do, and leads to misdiagnosis of problems as you have here.

If you fix the CRC code to stop hiding errors, you can at least find out what the real problem is. I.e. Add code to **report the error** as below.

```
Reset(F, 1);
if IOResult = 0 then
begin
  ...
end
else
begin
  RaiseLastOSError; //Defined in SysUtils
end;
```

---

#### UPDATE

Once you've learnt the real problem and why hiding errors is such a bad thing to do, I suggest you modernise your CRC code as explained below.

**NOTE** This code very deliberately does not make any attempt to hide errors.

- If you hide errors and something goes wrong, you're left puzzling why it's not working.
- If you ***don't hide*** errors and something goes wrong, you get an exception/error telling you what went wrong; and therefore half the work fixing the problem is done already!

Write an overload of `CalcCRC32` using `TStream`.

```
function CalcCRC32(AStream: TStream): Cardinal;
const CRCTable: array[0..255] of DWord =
     //Put your large const array here;
var
  LBytesRead: Integer;
  LBuffer: array[1..65521] of byte;
  LLoopI: Word;
begin
  Result := $ffffffff;

  repeat
    LBytesRead := AStream.Read(LBuffer, SizeOf(LBuffer));
    for LLoopI := 1 to LBytesRead do
    begin
      Result := (Result shr 8) xor CRCTable[LBuffer[LLoopI] xor (Result and $000000FF)];
    end;
  until LBytesRead = 0;

  Result := not Result;
end;
```

Then you can modify your existing routine as follows to keep calling code working as before.

```
procedure CalcCRC32(AFileName: String; var CRC32: DWORD);
var
  LStream: TStream;
begin
  LStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead, fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    CRC32 := CalcCRC32(LStream);
  finally
    LStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is GetLastError valid here? Isn't that mixing abstraction layers. If using Pascal I/O shouldn't you use Pascal error handling rather than win32?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Strictly speaking, yes. However, I did check the implementation of `_ResetFile` in `System.pas`, and it is using `CreateFile`. (At least for MSWINDOWS platform.) So it seemed the simplest most direct change for OP to see: (a) the real problem and (b) exactly why hiding errors is so bad. Of course, it would be worthwhile putting in the extra effort to update the code to use newer file handling classes or even `TStream`.

Comment: TStream is the only serious choice here

Comment: But if we must use Pascal I/O I think we should use its error handling mechanism. That's either $I+ or IOResult. It's important not to mix abstractions. Anyway the point is, as we both said, error checking must be added. If we are going to do that then we may as well switch bases to streams.

Comment: I deleted my answer then I'll leave you with the wheel you invented you self. The worst solution was what you wanted. Even though it is wrong

Comment: @David I agree it's important not to mix paradigms, but I consider the code to be throw-away (perhaps I should have stated as such). Reading `IOResult` means figuring out what reason the error code maps to. And dealing with the fact that after reading `IOResult`, it is automatically reset back to 0. Yes, they're easy problems to solve. It turns out that on Win platform, `IOResult` is set to `GetLastError`. So you could use `SysUtils.SysErrorMessage` to get an error string. Even if we're not leaning back towards mixed paradigms, it's extra unnecessary work.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt ***I*** did not invent this wheel. I'm just trying help help OP solve a problem and avoid similar mistakes in future. And your answer would have been perfectly acceptable if you just deleted the error hiding (which is the same mistake in OP's code). The IdHash implementation is unnecessarily overly complex for my tastes, but it certainly does the job. I see only one edge-case instance of error hiding: `if LSize < 1 then begin Break;  // TODO: throw a stream read exception instead?` _Yes, they should raise an exception. Especially considering how unlikely that error would be_.

Comment: @CraigYoung if you expect 100% bullet proof code then you should ask for it, You could Either remove  Result := -1;   if not FileExists(FileName) then
    exit; or take result in as a var parameter. Inventing the Wheel you self is ALWAYS wrong.

Comment: @Jens primarily what Craig (and myself) are doing is trying to help asker understand what was wrong. Very important to recognise the the code behaves identically on 64 bit. Also important to understand what went wrong and the importance of resilience. Error handling. CRC is very simple. I see no benefit in dragging, say, Indy, solely for that. I would resist that. Also, is Indy's the same CRC?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan inventing the wheel 500 times a day is the biggest mistake in the delphi world.

Comment: @Jens You said that. But you don't seem to address the other points. Is the Indy CRC the same as the one in the Q?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes it is! so you have inventet the wheel.

Comment: @Jens I don't understand that comment

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you should allways go for the build in function. You can easy write your own StrToInt function but why should you do that. And the same goes for calculating CRC if there are some "build in" code  doing it for you use that.

Comment: @Jens In this case though, you drag in Indy which may be undesirable. And CRC is simple to do. There are times when using built in doesn't get the job done. For performance I find it often necessary to avoid built in IntToStr because of the heap allocation. For instance. Sometimes we have to write code. But I argue that there's value in teaching this asker about why he had this problem. One learns from mistakes. Right?

Comment: @Jens I agree one shouldn't "reinvent the wheel without good cause". But since you conceded Indy's CRC and OP's CRC are basically the same, there's no immediate cause to believe OP's code shouldn't work. To continue the wheel anaology: You want to use a wheel built by Indy, OP built his own. Both wheels are round. The problem was OP put a clamp on his wheel. Unfortunately, you also **unnecessarily** put a clamp on your wheel. So how exactly do you expect your clamped wheel to work any better than OP's clamped wheel?

Comment: @Jens If you believe that OP has a bug in his re-invented implementation of CRC, then I challenge you to point out and explain the actual bug in his code.

Comment: I belive you missed the point: The CRC calculation could be done via buildin code.

Comment: @Jens I strongly urge you for ***your own benefit*** to take note of what I'm saying. If you properly read my comments, you'll see I clearly haven't missed the point. Just because it's built-in code doesn't mean you can't break it by wrapping it _incorrectly_. My answer doesn't tell OP to use IndyCRC because that's _irrelevant_ to OP's problem. If someone asks for help: why `if S = 'a' then Result := CustomStrToInt(S)` doesn't work, will replacing `CustomStrToInt` with the built-in `StrToInt` solve the problem?

Comment: @Jens Do you really think that comment is appropriate? I think it says a lot about why you're _choosing_ to remain ignorant.

Comment: @Jens Also, Indy isn't built in. It's a third party comms library that happens to ship with the product. Who wrote the Indy CRC code? If nobody wrote code where would we be? As Craig says, where's the problem in the asker's crc? A problem with your deleted answer is that your silence could easily be taken to infer agreement that asker's code was broken by the move to 64 bit. It's important to rebut that.

Answer (score 3):

That function operates the same in 32 bit as 64 bit. There is nothing to change.

If the file cannot be opened the function returns 0, because `not $ffffffff = $00000000`.

Thus I conclude that nothing more is happening here than your file not being found.

One problem with your code is that it doesn't give very identifiable error signals. When a file cannot be found, or is locked, or just happens to have a CRC value of 0, the outcome is the same. Which is really the root of your confusion. Some error handling should be added to make the failure modes distinguishable.

The code is also limited to operating on files. A stream based implementation would make it more flexible, and probably go a long way to making error handling easy to add.

Answer (score 0):

It should be: `fmOpenRead` **or** `fmShareDenyNone`, but for CRC32 calculation I would suggest to use `fmShareDenyWrite`

```
LStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
```